# S3 Static Website Nice URLs

Tags: url, amazon-s3, routes, seo

We are working on a website with a static frontend, API Gateway + Lambda as the backend, DynamoDB as the DB. I saw there were a couple similar questions to this one, but I'm looking to understand the matter throughly to build a complete and robust solutions, since I hope to build several websites using this stack.

This one is a fairly basic website: we have an `index.html` page, a `blog.html` page and a `portfolio.html` page. We also have an html page for single portfolio entries (let's call it `portfolio-entry.html`) and a page for single blog articles (let's call it `blog-post.html`).

So I see there's a way to specify an index page and an error page, so you can have a nice clean url for your index. There are also rewrite rules, which are more like redirects.

I guess my best bet to deliver different blog posts would be to pass a query string to `blog-post.html` ("mywebsite.com/blog-post.html?post=post-alias") and have the `.js` ask the API different content depending on the query string.

Is there a way using S3 to route `mywebsite.com/blog/post-alias/` to `mywebsite.com/blog-post.html?post=post-alias` and pass the response to the client without redirecting? I'm both interested in "client-side url rewriting" via JS to have nice URLs for humans AND server-side routing to catch crawler requests and have SEO/indexing of pages for specific posts, for example.

How should I go about this? Is there a way to achieve all this using what S3 and JS provide or do I have to put a proxy/router (like nginx) in front of S3 to handle route requests?

We are really committed to the whole S3-ApiGateway-Lambda-Dynamo architecture and we would really love to do without server.

Comment: *Is there a way using S3 to route a "mywebsite.com/blog/post-alias/" to "mywebsite.com/blog-post.html?post=post-alias" and pass the response to the client without redirecting?* Say again?  Ask S3 for one thing but get something different?  Like an internal S3 rewrite?  The browser address bar continues to show "mywebsite.com/blog/post-alias/"?  Without a redirect, the browser would not have a query string.

Comment: Take a look at the JAWS project ("*The Monstrously Scalable Serverless Framework*"): https://github.com/jaws-framework/JAWS